# Recurrent neural networks vs. State space models

Tags: reinforcement-learning, recurrent-neural-network, state-space-models

I'm trying to understand the differences between RNNs and State Space Models (SSMs). I know that SSMs can take on different definitions depending on who you ask, but here I define it as in [Learning Latent Dynamics for Planning from Pixels](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.04551.pdf).

Although this paper is about a new method, they do compare the graphical models associated with RNNs vs. SSMs:

[image: RNN vs. SSM]

Beneath this diagram they say: " Circles represent stochastic variables and squares deterministic variables. Solid lines denote the generative process
and dashed lines the inference model".

I understand that RNNs have deterministic states unlike SSMs (as they define them here). However, I often see RNNs visualized by an *input/output* diagram (unfolded RNN diagram) like so:

[image: RNN input/output diagram.]

Ignoring the actions $a_t$ and rewards $r_t$ (the paper is an RL paper), considering $x_t$ to be $o_t$, and supposing that $y_t$ is a prediction for *the next state* $h_{t+1}$, it seems as though the canonical diagram of an RNN is simply the "inference model" of a state space model where the states are deterministic.

So can we say that the relationship between RNN and SSMs is that RNNs *directly* model the "inference model" $p(h_{t+1}|h_t, x_t)$, while SSMs model the *generative model* (transition model + observation model) and then "do inference" by computing the necessary posteriors?

**note**: I've been looking over these diagrams for a bit so the differing notation doesn't bother me. However, I'm not sure if it is very annoying as a viewer. If so, please comment and I will try and edit.

Comment: Note: What you call the "input/output diagram" of a RNN is also referred to as the "unfolded" representation of that network.

Comment: also note that the RNN can take much reacher architectures, you can have skip connections, deep networks, different activations, and so on